# how to get div attributes into json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following div

```
<div class="specialbreaek">
```

This div is stored in a JavaScript variable

I want to convert this into json so that i can get the class name easily

I tried JSON.parse() but still not get the required result

Any Help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance !

Comment: "This div is stored in a JavaScript variable"  Can you show us what you mean by that?

Comment: Could you please share your Javascript code? You said you have stored div in Javascript variable, but How ?

Comment: "I want to convert this into json" what are you referring to here ?

Comment: if you need to get `class` attirbute value then simply get it using `attr()` method: `$("div").attr("class");`

Comment: i have this div in the json response and i want to go further to access its class name

Comment: do you have anything else to add to your question or does one of the answers help ?

Comment: @j.bush answer helped me some how

Answer (score 1):

I see a few solutions depending on what you mean by "JavaScript variable". If the element is stored as a string, you can use a combinations of `String.prototype.search()` and `String.prototype.substring()` to extract the class. For example:

```js
var s = '<div class="specialbreaek">';
var index = s.search(new RegExp(/class=".*"/, 'i'));
s = s.substring(index + 7);
var index = s.search(new RegExp(/"/, 'i'));
s = s.substring(0,index);
document.write(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you have a `div` with several attributes and you want to extract them (using JS) and convert them into a JSON string.

If that's the case, you can use this to extract all attributes and then use any method you want to concatenate them into JSON

```js
$(function() {
  var mydiv = $("#mydiv");
  var results = "";


  // The attributes property contains all attributes of an element
  $.each(mydiv.prop('attributes'), function(index, attr) {
    // this.attributes is not a plain object, but an array
    // of attribute nodes, which contain both the name and value
    results += attr.name + ":" + attr.value;
    results += ", ";
  });
  $("#res").text(results);
  console.log(results);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv" class="myclass" style="mystyle">
  my div text
</div>

<hr/>
<h2>results</h2>
<div id="res"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert javascript variable into Json is `JSON.stringify`

Try this

```
$(function(){
  var element = $(".specialbreaek");
  var jsonstr = JSON.stringify(element);
  console.log(jsonstr);
})
```

It will output this.

```
{"0":{},"length":1,"prevObject":{"0":{},"context":{},"length":1},"context":{},"selector":".specialbreaek"}
```